# Best way to find which port is selected from client-side

Tags: python, sockets, networking, multiprocessing, threadpool

My program randomly selects a port server-side using address `('0.0.0.0', 0)` and a unique `code` is sent to the client-side where the socket is trying to connect to every port within a range and checking for the same `code` to confirm the correct server port.

The problem is iterating through all the ports (`range(1024, 65336)`), and trying to connect to each one of them is very slow even if `ThreadPool` is used.

---

This is just an example to show what I'm trying to do. My main program host over the internet not on localhost.

*server.py*

```py
import socket 

CODE = 'Code123' # just an example

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
addr = ('0.0.0.0', 0)
server.bind(addr)

# Can see which port is assigned
print(server)

def start():
    server.listen(5) # connect to 5 connection.
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        conn.send(CODE.encode('utf-8'))
        print("Code Sent")

start()
```

*cilent.py*

```py
import socket
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

code = 'Code123' # just an example
server = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port_left = 65336
found = False

def connect(port):
    global port_left, code, server, found
    if found: return
    port_left -= 1
    try:
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect((server, port))
        if client.recv(len(code)).decode('utf-8') == code:
            found = True
            return client
        else: client.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, port_left)
    return None

pool = ThreadPool(10)
values = [('c', i) for i in set(pool.map(connect, range(1024, 65336))) if i]
client = dict(values).get('c')
pool.close()
pool.join()
print(client)
```

---

Is there a better way to achieve this goal or improve the performance of my existing code?

Comment: If you think about it like this: If one of either your server or client has to initiate the conversation with the other, which one is more logical to have a "fixed" port that the service resides on? Set a static-port there, and then reply to the port that the message is coming from on that device.

Comment: What's the purpose of the random socket, why not just have a fixed port? This also avoids the problem of collisions with other server software ports.

Comment: To add another example of how to think: HTTP usually responds on TCP-port 80. So the Server has its web-service serving HTTP-requests that land on that port. However, the client doesn't have a specific TCP-port that its meant for them to send it's requests from, so the server responds to the TCP-port that it received the message from. And thus, they can have a conversation with each other.

Comment: @HampusLarsson: What if that fixed port is later busy by someone else and my script tries to connect with the same port?

Comment: For this reason you'll want to make it configurable. Or pick a port you know won't be taken by something else on your device. Still confused as to the reasoning behind making it random though.

Comment: I can shorten the range of available ports which will work just fine, but I'm still looking for a robust solution

Comment: You won't get a more robust solution without libraries like nmap unfortunately, brute forcing ports is likely all you can achieve with built-ins.

Comment: "What if that fixed port is later busy..." That should _never_ happen. As in, if the server is configured and running, nothing should be able to use that port on the server. There in lies the problem with your way of thinking. Please check [a list of well-known ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) and either choose the port that does exactly what your application is trying to do, or add "backup" ports that the service should use.

Comment: @HampusLarsson: Very helpful link of the well-known port you shared, Now I understand properly what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but too long for a comment.

This is not the way random ports are expected to be used. They are used for the data connection in the FTP protocol that way (passive mode):

- the client opens the control connection on a well known port (21)
- it asks the server for a random data port *through the control connection*
- it opens the data connection *knowing its port*

Opening a connection on random ports should be avoided, because if the server does not answer immediately, the client has to wait for a timeout to decide whether the server was just busy or not there.

So my advice if you want to use random ports is to keep one well known port on which the client will get the real random port.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it through the answer, this is simple and easy. Also you said *not the way random ports are expected to be used*, So can a well-known port be used to establish a connection with multiple clients and sending large data?

Comment: @Saad: There are 2 good examples of sending large data while serving many clients: the FTP and the HTTP protocol. HTTP uses one single well known port (80) for client commands and data. FTP uses one well known port for the command, and random ports for the data (one port per data connection). The nice part was that it allowed a client to initiate a transfert between 2 remote hosts. But this feature was soon deprecated because it was used to initiate DoD attacks. Random ports are now frowned upon because they cause headaches to firewall managers...

Answer (score 0):

[nmap](https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/) provides ways to do this. Here's the example code from [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/port-scanner-using-python-nmap/):

```
import nmap 

# take the range of ports to  
# be scanned 
begin = 75
end = 80

# assign the target ip to be scanned to 
# a variable 
target = '127.0.0.1'

# instantiate a PortScanner object 
scanner = nmap.PortScanner() 

for i in range(begin,end+1): 

    # scan the target port 
    res = scanner.scan(target,str(i)) 

    # the result is a dictionary containing  
    # several information we only need to 
    # check if the port is opened or closed 
    # so we will access only that information  
    # in the dictionary 
    res = res['scan'][target]['tcp'][i]['state'] 

    print(f'port {i} is {res}.')
```

Output:

```
port 75 is closed.
port 76 is closed.
port 77 is closed.
port 78 is closed.
port 79 is closed.
port 80 is open.
```

However, I will say that randomly assigning a server port is not practical, and you're likely better off just assigning a fixed port.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would like to do this without any external package.

Comment: If you're not using any external packages then your method of creating a socket and seeing if it connects is likely already the best way to do this. It'll be slow but it works.